# how to call background function from web controller in yii2

Tags: php, background, controller, console, yii2

I have a controller function that save some file in DB and then create personal PDF file for every record in DB and email it to him . The problem is that it take to much time. Can I call console controller from the web controller function and pass the id to the console function? Or there is a better or other method to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think calling console command from web controller will help too much.

But for this purpose you can use for example [this extension](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension).

**Usage:**

Imported class:

```
use vova07\console\ConsoleRunner;
$cr = new ConsoleRunner(['file' => '@my/path/to/yii']);
$cr->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...');
```

Application component:

```
// config.php
...
components [
    'consoleRunner' => [
        'class' => 'vova07\console\ConsoleRunner',
        'file' => '@my/path/to/yii' // or an absolute path to console file
    ]
]
...

// some-file.php
Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...');
```

But I recommend to use work queues for that like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), these are more suitable for your task.

Comment: i already try to use this but its try to use the php.exe file in C: and in my server there is no such file in C: . how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think is better you use a proper class with proper function/metohd , share this in common area and invoke the function  in the different controllers

common model

```
    namespace common\models;

    use Yii;

    /**
     * This is the model class for table "c2_common_user_param".
     *
     * @property integer $id
     * @property integer $user_id
     * @property string $land_scope_code
     * @property string $init_lat
     * @property string $init_lng
     * @property integer $init_zoom
     * @property string $google_maps_api_key
     *
     * @property DfenxUser $user
     */
    class UserParam extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'c2_common_user_param';
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['user_id'], 'required'],
                [['user_id', 'init_zoom'], 'integer'],
                [['init_lat', 'init_lng'], 'number'],
                [['land_scope_code'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
                [['google_maps_api_key'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
                'user_id' => Yii::t('app', 'User ID'),
                'land_scope_code' => Yii::t('app', 'Land Scope Code'),
                'init_lat' => Yii::t('app', 'Init Lat'),
                'init_lng' => Yii::t('app', 'Init Lng'),
                'init_zoom' => Yii::t('app', 'Init Zoom'),
                'google_maps_api_key' => Yii::t('app', 'Google Maps Api Key'),
            ];
        }
    }
```

backend controller

```
    <?php

    namespace backend\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use common\models\UserParam;
    use common\models\UserParamSearch;

    use common\models\User;

    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


    /**
     * UserParamController implements the CRUD actions for UserParam model.
     */
    class UserParamController extends Controller
    {
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Lists all UserParam models.
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $searchModel = new UserParamSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }

     }
```

frontend controller

```
    <?php

    namespace frontend\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use common\models\UserParam;
    use common\models\UserParamSearch;

    use common\models\User;

    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


    /**
     * UserParamController implements the CRUD actions for UserParam model.
     */
    class UserParamController extends Controller
    {
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * Lists all UserParam models.
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $searchModel = new UserParamSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }

     }
```

Comment: so how can i call the function in background?? can you write / link me some example?
thanks